# Lenovo Y70 is very slow

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-geforce

Recently I purchased a [Lenovo Y70 Touch](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y70-touch/) with pre-installed Windows 8.1 for my girlfriend. It seemed to fit her usage as a casual gamer. However, it's become very slow, after a few weeks of usage. Simple browsing and streaming works fairly well but games are completly unplayable as they lag severely. From simple games like Agar.io or old games like Fallout 2 to more advanced like Star Craft 2. It's a far cry from this review: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-Y70-Notebook-Review.128841.0.html

I've tried the following to no avail:

- Updating nVidia drivers to the latest
- Changing the settings to make nVidia my default graphics card
- Disabling internal graphics card
- Scanning for malware and viruses

Another thing that bothers me is the nVidia control panel which only shows 3D-settings and nothing more:
[image]

The only thing I haven't done is completely whiping the computer and make a clean install with one of my own Windows 8.1 licenses. But I would think that dispite all the pre-installed "bloatware" simple games would still run smothely. After all, I payed for "Best Touch Screen Gaming Laptop" as Lenovo boasts. I wouldn't think that everything that comes pre-installed would slow it down THAT much. I would think that I can use it right off the bat.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The machine has 16 GB

Comment: Limited NVIDIA Control Panel is normal. Can you post a screenshot of *Manage 3D settings* section, *Global settings* tab? http://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8ls.png

Comment: Uninstall everything that is *handy* but *unneccesary* - especially syncing tools and browser plugins. And kill the bloatware.

Comment: @gronostaj I have the nVidia-card selected.

Comment: I have the y70 and games run AMAZING, so I feel there's probably something you can do. Did you ever find a solution? Obviously keep the power cord plugged in and make sure it's not on "energy saver" mode

Answer (score 0):

The clue is "However, it's become very slow, after a few weeks of usage." What has been done to the laptop over that time? What does *Task Manager* show as **running processes** in the *Details* tab? The most likely cause of any slowdown is one or more process competing for CPU time. Installed apps, though "bloatware", do *not* slow the machine unless they are actively running.
[image]

After determining the issue, investigate the processes. **Do not arbitrarily
kill or disable processes consuming time.** For example, Windows 8 automatically checks and optimizes disks; if the machine is turned on only infrequently, these processes will un until tasks complete (If that is the cause, let required tasks run overnight.).

If you need help determining what processes are slowing the laptop, take a screenshot of *Task Manager* sorted  by CPU usage.

Comment: The thing is, there isn't much activity in the Task Managers. As I write this, it's under 10% CPU and 30% memory. And even as i write, the keyboard delays with about 0,5 sec. EVERYTHING lags on it.